# Isn't a video search by keyword for OAuth authorized users?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have implemented search.list kind of like docs points https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

But I found out about the quota unit.

So I made an OAuth 2.0 flow, so the user can log in with it's own account and then not dry my own quota, because I mistakenly thought videos.list was a sort of authorized way to get search by keyword https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

So, even tho the user is authorized, all search.list request will be excuted using apiKey and not OAuth credentials??

Answer (score 0):

There is one quota limit for your whole app. So all your users have to share it.

That said, it’s a good idea to have the OAuth2 flow and with it using the users own api key with the search requests because there is also a quota limit that applies to X amount of request in 100 seconds by a given user. This limit is very high but it eases the situation when many users work with your tool in parallel.